# Diagram tree using reat- konva

Tags: react-konva

Hi i am completely new to konva,
I know how to create basic shapes using konva,I want a create a digram tree. I tried many ways but it's not working
Can any one suggest and guide me to create digram tree with react konva connected with arrows.